# Inconsistent rails method `exists` and `any?`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails based chat. So I initially create a conversation between 2 clients when they add each other as friends and my model for `Conversation` is as follows:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :player_client
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Now when the `player_client` clicks a specific button I want to create an automated message for them. This should only happen if they've never sent a message to each other i.e. the conversation has no associated messages.

Trying the following methods from the console:

```
@conversation = Conversation.find(7)
@conversation.messages.any?
> False
@conversation.messages.empty?
> True
@conversation.messages.exists?
> False
```

Which are all expected values. But adding any of these methods in my Rails code throws an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `messages' for #<Conversation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fa187ca1ec8>)`
```

Which I guess is showing up because messages don't exist for that conversation so it can't find any association for that conversation. I'm not sure why this method would be inconsistent though.

EDIT: Adding the error causing code.

conversation_with_player_client = @client.conversations.select{|c| c.player_client_id == @game.player_client.id}

```
if conversation_with_player_client.count == 0
  @conversation = @client.conversations.build({player_client_id: @game.player_client.id})
  @conversation.save!
else
  @conversation = @client.conversations.where({ player_client_id: @game.player_client.id })
end

puts "the conversation we found was #{@conversation.inspect}"
# This gives the response
# #<Conversation id: 7, player_client_id: 1, client_id: 11, created_at: "2018-02-12 20:55:55", updated_at: "2018-02-12 20:55:55">
# in the console so it can get the conversation 

if @conversation.messages.any?

# this line is causing the error
```

Comment: You should post the code that causes the error, but it seems you are applying the `.messages` to many conversations (or other association) and not a unique conversation.

Comment: @Pablo I added the code block as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is due to you calling `messages` on a *collection* of conversations rather than a *single* conversation.

I'd be willing to bet the offending code is something like:

`client.conversations.messages #=> NoMethodError`

Instead, it should be:

`client.conversations.first.messages`

EDIT - this is the line causing the error:

`@conversation = @client.conversations.where({ player_client: @game.player_client.id })`

`where` will return a relation representing many conversations. If you only want a single conversation, you can use `find_by`:

`@conversation = @client.conversations.find_by({ player_client: @game.player_client.id })`

Comment: That's what I thought, but considering the fact that I'm looking for the appropriate conversation using the `where` clause and since only one conversation can exist like this so it shouldn't be the case right?

Comment: `where` always returns a relation, not a single instance. which is nice, because you don't have to worry about what it's returning. but in this case, you need `find_by` or `where(...).first`

Comment: Hmm okay, that makes sense. Thanks for the detailed explanation, I'm sure it'll help me a lot in the future also

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with `present?` method? Guess it would work better... like this:

```
@conversation.messages.present?
```

It will return false if messages is nil or empty, so I guess it fits better. Good luck!

Comment: It's still the same, maybe the information I added would help?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
@conversation = @client.conversations.where({ player_client: @game.player_client.id })
```

is not a conversation. Is more than one. You cannot use messages there.

If you need only one conversation, you must change where by find_by.

If not, you need to iterate through all conversations.

Comment: So what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Already in the answer. Use find_by to select only one conversation

Answer (score 0):

The another way with `find_or_create_by` method:

```
@client.conversations.find_or_create_by(player_client: @game.player_client.id)
```

To find more info:

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by